# Matching regular expression at the end of the string with Python 2.7.13

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have the following string:

```
fo = "b---00b<do:YYYY>tftt_<fd>-<fd><ct><ct:MM>mmm.pdf"
```

And I only want to get `mmm.pdf`.

When I try:

```
match = re.search(r'(>.*?\.pdf)', fo)

for g in match.groups():
    print g
```

I get:

```
>tftt_<fd>-<fd><ct><ct:MM>mmm.pdf
```

I though the `?` symbol will make the search stop at the first `>`, but the pattern `(>.*\.pdf)` gives me the same result.
Which is the correct regular expression for getting `mmm.pdf`?

`mmm.pdf` can be `abcs.pdf`, `qwerty123.pdf`, etc. And `fo` always have the format:

```
fo = "someOptionalstring<otherstring>anotherOptionalString<string>optionalstring<string>mmm.pdf"
```

The alternation between `strings` (can be empty) and `<strings>` (not empty) can be in any amount. I could find regular expressions to extract these values, but not the desired string at the end.

I could use an algorithm using `endswith()` and looking for the last `>` character, but I want to try regular expressions for learning purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[^>]*\.pdf` instead:

where `[^>]*` means 0 or more any character that is not `>`

```
fo = "b---00b<do:YYYY>tftt_<fd>-<fd><ct><ct:MM>mmm.pdf"
match = re.search(r'([^>]*\.pdf)', fo)
for g in match.groups():
    print g
```

**Output:**

```
mmm.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works if there is always 3 characters preceding dot.
match=re.search('>(.{3}\.pdf)',fo)